# org-mode exclude fullpage.sty from latex preview preamble

Tags: latex, org-mode, preview

Using `fullpage.sty` in a document preamble breaks latex preview by generating a full page preview images with page numbers. I.e., this code:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
```

will generate the preview image:

[image]

How to exclude `fullpage` package from LaTeX preview preamble? Also, is it a bug and needs a bug report?

Comment: I have a feeling that this should go to the [TeX-LaTeX stack exchange forum](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please also upload the image here. Your dropbox link will expire one day, and this question will stay.

Comment: Can't you just drop the `fullpage` from you preamble? Otherwise I don't understand the question...

Comment: Well, I need the fullpage.sty when export to PDF, but not need it when LaTeX preview. I.e. "just drop" is not a solving, but a hack.

Comment: @sdorof: It's clear then... I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [org-latex-preview#Minted](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html#sec-6-2) if you add the `fullpage.sty` package to `org-latex-packages-alist` in your emacs configuration file like so:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "fullpage" nil))
```

it should use it for exporting but not for the preview.